# Stop criterium for fixed point methods

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Let $g(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ define a fixed point method.
We are interested in the points $\alpha$ s.t. $\alpha = g(\alpha)$.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be defined by $x_{n+1} := g(x_n)$.
Suppose that $x_n \to \alpha \ (n \to +\infty)$.

How to prove the following?

If $g$ sufficiently smooth in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$, then

\begin{equation}
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists m > 0 \ \big(( \ \forall n > m \ \vert x_n - x_{n-1} \vert < \varepsilon) \rightarrow \ (\exists C > 0 \ \forall n > m \ \vert x_n - \alpha\vert < C\varepsilon)\big).
\end{equation}

In other words the theorem assures that we can safely estimate the error of an iterative fixed point method in a certain iteration, looking a the value $\vert x_n - x_{n-1}\vert$.

Comment: I think I found a proof, I will answer now

Comment: I think your last inequality which should not be strict or $x_n = \alpha$ gives a problem. More importantly, I believe your final conclusion is not supported by your result. I do not see a *practical* way to verify that your hypothesis is satisfied. If your focus is actual computation of a computer, your fixed point iteration could be investigated in terms of the Lipschitz constants and the forward relative error when computing values of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be $C^{(1)}$ in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$.
Furthermore we suppose $g'(\alpha) \neq 1$, otherwise more regularity is required.
From Taylor we have
\begin{equation}
x-g(x) = \alpha - g(\alpha) + (x-\alpha) (1-g'(\alpha)) + o(x-\alpha).
\end{equation}
Substituting $x_n$ to $x$ we get
\begin{equation}
x_n - x_{n+1} = (x_n - \alpha)(1-g'(\alpha)) + o(x_n - \alpha).
\end{equation}
Then for 
\begin{equation}
C := \left\Vert \frac{1}{1 - g'(\alpha)} \right\Vert_{\infty},
\end{equation}
where the norm is taken in the interval in which the Taylor expansion is defined, we have the thesis.

We have also proved that $C$ is independent from $\varepsilon$.

Comment: A similar conclusion follows also from Banach-Cacioppoli Theorem